# Jenkins pipeline - Only run test job once in a sequence of jobs?

Tags: git, jenkins, bitbucket, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

We have our pipeline set up where we kick off a job every time there's a push on a branch. We have our tests separated out into its own repo. In a simple case, it'd look something like:

```
Repo0 Job ---> RepoTest Job
```

With downstream jobs, it gets a little messy:

```
Repo1 ---> RepoTest
      ---> Repo2 ---> RepoTest
                 ---> Repo4 ---> RepoTest
      ---> Repo3 ---> RepoTest
```

Is there a smart way, without just using a constant time delay, to only kick off the tests ONCE after all the downstream jobs finish? Something like:

```
Repo1 ---> Repo2 ---> Repo4 ---> RepoTest
      ---> Repo3
```

Would also have cases where Repo2 is where the change is, so would only want to kick off the tests once Repo4 is done without considering Repo1 or Repo3. Note: this is all a simplified example of our situation. We could have a sequence of more than 20 jobs kicking off.

Currently set it up so we just trigger the tests X amount of time based on which repo the change is located on. Not ideal.

Comment: Is there a pre-defined list of downstream jobs? If yes, then you have a final downstream job that runs at the very end (repo4 in the above example). You could have the RepoTest job set as the downstream job for the repo4 job which means it only runs once all the jobs are complete.

Comment: The chain of jobs is a lot more complicated than my quick example. In the final branch, so to speak, of downstream jobs, there's probably around 8 or so jobs that finish at various times. There isn't a single job at the end which is the problem here. Trying to make my test job that final job.

But yes, there is a pre-defined list of downstream jobs

Answer (score 0):

If you could live with the upstream jobs waiting for the downstream jobs to finish you could conditionally trigger tests at the end of every job if the job was triggered by an scm event or skip them if the job was triggered by another job.

It means you are adding logic to every *build* job, but I just don't see how your *test* job would know what to wait for before it runs.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand here - I could add code so a job, kicked off by a push, can check all the downstream jobs? Even the ones kicked off by other downstream jobs?

Comment: @john The other way around - the upstream job doesn't care what happens to the downstream jobs, it just waits for them to finish and then checks if it was triggered by a push, which presumably means that it's the root job and if it calls the test job it will be called only once. Every downstream job does the same - it waits for its downstream jobs to finish and then checks if it was triggered by a push event, but it wouldn't be (because it was triggered by an upstream job) and it doesn't call the test job.